# Put together several messages into one conversation in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I think Gmail is the first webmail provider that features the Conversation -- having only one mailbox entry for messages in the same thread. Neat.

However, a downside to this is that when you edit the subject just a wee bit (even just one character), that new message breaks apart from the rest of the Conversation and itself creates a new thread. Yes, changing the subject does have its benefits.

Can I put together several related messages into one Conversation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design, so it is not possible. There is no mechanism to merge conversations and the only way to split a conversation is to change the subject, even if it's only one character.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I want to vote down the content... there should be a way to merge conversations.

Comment: I agree, it should be possible to move a message into a conversation or move a message out of a conversation that doesn't belong there. And sometimes I want to update the subject line *without* having it start a new conversation. I should have that option. It's limitations like these that sometimes tempt me to switch back to using a local app like Thunderbird...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

If you want to put two e-mails together into a conversation, **forward** one of the e-mails to yourself using *the subject line from the other e-mail*.

It's not pretty (it obscures the original sender a bit, as well as the timeline if you do it after other messages in the conversation roll in), but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new label and put several conversations under the same label, so anytime you can easily find conversations you linked via the label.