# Grouping Gmail messages with different subjects under the same conversation

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Put together several messages into one conversation in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12874/put-together-several-messages-into-one-conversation-in-gmail)
>   [Can I merge two conversation threads in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/176/can-i-merge-two-conversation-threads-in-gmail)

My application sends out related emails with different subjects. It would be nice to group them all into the same conversation.

I tried setting the "In-Reply-To" and "References" E-mail headers but Gmail still keeps the messages separate.

Is there a way to force messages with different subject lines into the same conversation?

Comment: Not possible. This question is similar to (and may be a duplicate of) one of these: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12874/put-together-several-messages-into-one-conversation-in-gmail http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/176/can-i-merge-two-threads-in-gmail