# Gmail merges IFTTT emails into conversations even with different subjects

Tags: gmail, if-this-then-that, reddit

I have a IFTTT recipe, which mails me on new posts on a certain subreddit. The subject looks like:

```
[IFTTT] {{Title}} via /r/{{Subreddit}}
```

In Gmail I have a filter that filters on `from:(action@ifttt.com)`, which skips inbox and applies a label.

Now when e-mails come in, they have different subjects, but they still get merged into conversations—how do I stop that? Some e-mails get merged, others do not.

It seems that my question is the opposite of what [Grouping Gmail messages with different subjects under the same conversation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13411/grouping-gmail-messages-with-different-subjects-under-the-same-conversation) is trying to establish.

Edit: I'm now trying to throw away all mails in the filter, maybe that'll help.

Edit 2: Didn't help, I've received two emails, with different subjects, which are still combined into one conversation.

Comment: Look at the message headers (_Show original_). Is there an `In-Reply-To` or similar header?

Comment: No, there is no header that contains the word `Reply`..

Comment: If your custom filter is not set, do they still get grouped?  Is there any chance you could provide two sample email header sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have resolved my problem.

I have replaced the subject line by
`{{Subreddit}} {{Title}} via /r/{{Subreddit}}`, and now it does not merge them anymore..

To test whether the tag [IFFT] made them merge, I've tried mailing myself from a different address using a tag, but those were not merged.